# How can I make LEDs brightness more uniform vs. battery consumption?

Tags: led, batteries

I have a PCB that has an array of indicator LEDs that blink for about 20 minutes per day. With fresh batteries (2xAA in series, 3 V), the LEDs blink brightly. Once the battery voltage goes down the LEDs become more dim. Is there any way to keep the luminous output of the LEDs more constant as the battery voltage goes down?

Comment: Use some feedback to hold the LED's at the lowest voltage the battery would cover.  SO if the 9V range is really 5.5V to 9V, regulate the power at 5.5V and only drive the LED with that.  So as the battery discharges the voltage used to drive the LED's stays constant (Until the battery drops too much)

Comment: How many LEDs and how much voltage headroom do you have for each of them (I'm assuming just the 3V minus the required operating voltage, but I want to be sure)? How are they driven so that they blink?

Comment: If the brightness were more uniform, how would you know when the batteries need replacing?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a DC-DC transformer step-up or step-down depending on the voltage you need. I have found an example [here](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/like/191696467349?lpid=122&chn=ps&adgroupid=28306099746&rlsatarget=pla-184492184946&adtype=pla&poi=&googleloc=9044908&device=c&campaignid=628859225&crdt=0). 
 **Edit:** This exact DC-DC converter needs a minimum in voltage of 5V your 2 AA will not supply enough you could add two more to reach 6V or you could use [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-DC-Input-0-8-3V-Output-3-3V-Step-UP-Power-Converter-Voltage-Module-RF-/231083181020).

Comment: 4V min needs to drop a bit limit load current for stepup and will be low efficiency when Vout is near Vin. Step down from a bigger cell voltage is doable .

Comment: XL3009 needs 5Vin min and Vout min =4V? I believe

Answer (score 0):

95% efficient boost regulators are possible if rewired in series.
~85%buck regulator to drop to CC regulated brightness will reduce time of discharge useage.

Ideally you want to match voltage of parallel LEDS 1SxP,array to constant voltage battery.

The best bet for simplicity is a 3.0V non rechargeable Lithium CR2 rated at 2450mAh direct to all LEDs in parallel which are nominally 3.1 V depending on chip size and ESR of LED (~15 Ohms for 5mm)so they won't run at full brightness.

Li Cells are very precise CV cells of 3.0 V

e.g. http://www.batterybuyer.com/duracell-ultra-photo-lithium-volt-battery-dlcr2-p-10231.html?gclid=Cj0KEQjw3ZS-BRD1xu3qw8uS2s4BEiQA2bcfM8zlNiuQiI__dc0sQfJr5ZnWj36c5ag_2U8hArzBIUYaAl7l8P8HAQ

next option is a 3.7V LiPo with a Buck CC regulator or ultralow LDO with xxx mA drive or CC circuit based using a precision Vref. But even these will drop to 3.3V

Answer (score 0):

Well, one thing comes to mind about your LED situation. But you haven't said anything yet about how you drive them to make them blink. That said, I can at least convey an idea to consider. Let's say your voltage rail can run well from a voltage anywhere from \$Vcc=2\cdot 1.55V=3.1V\$ from a fresh set of  AA batteries to \$Vcc=2\cdot 1.1V=2.2V\$ for a nearly depleted set. Let's also assume that your LEDs require about \$V_{led}\approx 2V\$ to operate at \$I_{led}=20mA\$. Let's target that for now. I'll leave the details about how you operate each LED to you, since you give nothing much to go on, sadly. (I don't know how many, I don't know if they need to be individually controlled to blink, I don't know how you blink them, I don't know the LED specifications.... A pretty sad state of affairs given you are asking for help.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzg3EU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The idea here is to provide a reasonably constant current to each of the LEDs. The above circuit should provide somewhere between \$19mA\$ and \$21mA\$ to the LEDs over the \$V_{CC}\$ voltage range just mentioned earlier.

Analysis: Let's ignore the base currents required by all the transistors to keep it clean, at first, and discuss those problems, later. There are two basic circuits. The first is the one that sets the desired current in the LEDs and hopefully manages to do that over variations in the supply voltage. This circuit is actively driven by \$Q_{100}\$ and relies on \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ to complete the circuit. This circuit sets the current sourced out of \$Q_0\$, which is itself part of a current mirror chain. \$Q_0\$ and \$Q_1 \ldots Q_n\$ represent the current mirror used to deliver the right current into each LED. The current programmed by \$Q_100\$, \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ sets the \$V_{BE}\$ of \$Q_0\$. This voltage is then distributed to each of \$Q_1 \ldots Q_n\$ and sets their collector currents, which are then used to source each of the LEDs.

There is a problem, in that each of the base currents do impact the accuracy and more transistors in the chain will have their base currents add up to a larger error. But that can be finessed by making changes in \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$, as needed.

There is yet another serious problem, too. If you look closely, you can see that the collectors of LED drivers \$Q_1 \ldots Q_n\$ are at \$2V\$. But their emitters might be at \$2.2V\$ when the power supply is low. This means they will definitely be in saturation, then. Not when \$V_{CC}=3V\$. But certainly as the voltage level declines. That's going to tax the current setting circuit and cause errors. I could insert another BJT in order to compensate for that, but that would mean another \$V_{BE}\$ of required headroom and, quite frankly, you don't have enough there. So .. nope. You will just have to accept and live with the problem. At least, I think, it should be better than doing nothing at all.

The computation for the values of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ (ignoring the base current complications) is pretty easy. \$R_1\$ should be assumed to drop about one \$V_{BE}\approx 750mV\$ for \$Q_{100}\$. You also want \$R_2\$ to force some modest collector current at all times in \$Q_100\$ (otherwise the circuit isn't stable against changes in \$V_{CC}\$.) When \$V_{CC} = 2.2V\$ then you should be able to see that there will only be about \$V\left(R_2\right) = 2.2V - 1.5V = 700mV\$ across it. That needs to supply the \$20mA\$ needed through \$R_1\$ plus any extra for the collector of \$Q_{100}\$. I'm going to set that collector current to be \$10mA\$ at this low voltage, so the value will be \$R_2 = \frac{700mV}{10mA+20mA}\approx 23\Omega\$. Let's round that down to a standard value of \$R_2=22\Omega\$. Now, \$R_1=\frac{750mV}{20mA}=37.5\Omega\$. Let's round that to the standard value of \$R_1=39\Omega\$.

That should do it for a possible model to consider. I don't know if this is just unacceptable to you, or not. But it provides a possible path to consider.

It does not currently provide you any way to blink the LEDs. And it doesn't provide individual control for each of the LEDs. And it doesn't deal well with situations where one or more of the LEDs are off when others are on. It's not supposed to do any of that, though. I just wanted to suggest a pathway to consider, first. Then, if you are still interested the rest can always be added.